# Error: Initializers may only be declared within a type

Tags: ios, swift

Here's my code

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1)) {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        init(CGImage: image.CGImage!)
    }
}
```

On `init(CGImage: image.CGImage!)`, I get the error

> Initializers may only be declared within a type

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The dedicated initializer is called from the convenience initializer
with `self.init(...)`:

```
self.init(CGImage: image.CGImage!)
```

Without `self.` (or `super.` if you call the superclass initializer)
the compiler mistakes `init(...)` for the *declaration* of an init
method.

Comment: Oh yes! My bad, must have removed while refactoring code. Thanks,